# Does "Detach Elements to Work with Them" improve performance always?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I learned from Jquery performance guide(http://learn.jquery.com/performance/detach-elements-before-work-with-them/) that detaching element when working with them improve performance. But I want to know whether this will improve performance even when reading from DOM or only when processing the DOM?

Comment: I don't think there will be any difference if it is only a read operation

Comment: There is not so much difference: http://jsperf.com/test-detach-perf-on-reading

Comment: @roasted Thank you for the test proof

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It improves performance when you make *modifications* to the element that would cause reflows, i.e. the browser would have to recompute the layout of the element.

Reading the DOM *usually* does not cause reflows.

As far as I know, reading certain layout information (such as the offset of an element) can trigger reflows to ensure that the correct values are returned. But in such a case, you probably want the element to be part of the document since you might not get accurate information otherwise.

Comment: doesn't reading layout related information cause reflows?  ISTR reading about that somewhere.

Comment: Yep, me too, just updated my answer. Unfortunately I don't know that much about it.